# Can't add new node via model in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

Hi I am using [kartik tree view](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-tree-manager). I have added a model. Now I want to add new node(s) to it but I am getting an error.

```
 $n = new MdcNode;
            $n->root = MdcNode::idToid($m->node_id);
            $n->lft = $query['rgt'] + 1;
            $n->rgt = $n->lft + 1;
            $n->lvl = 1;
            $n->name = $m->customer_name;
            $n->icon = "user";
$n->save()
```

> Method "common\models\MdcNode::insert" is not supported for inserting new nodes.

How can I insert a new record?

Comment: You need to use dedicated API to insert new records in the tree. See https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets#usage

Comment: @rob006 should I skip using kartik tree ?

Comment: You need to create new nodes in tree using linked API. You can't just save records setting all fields manually.